# how to solve the type and namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, namespaces, mono

I am trying to make a cross platform application using MONO. i developed the project into c#(windows) and I want to run that project into Linux. For that purpose i am using MONO.But when i am running my project then I am getting error that  ***the type and namespace could not be found***.Actually I have created two partition of the project ,one is main function and other is the rest of the logic.And to access the other functionality i am using the namespace.but when i am running i am getting error

[image]

***Here is the line where i am getting error in line 2 and 3***

[image]

Comment: I have added the dll into my project.when i running on console it is running fine but when i am running through mono then i am facing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the referenced assembly path using -pkg switch. I think you did not reference VehicleRoutPlannerCore dll while compiling.

Please refer to http://linux.die.net/man/1/mcs

you should invoke it like

```
mcs -pkg:path-to-VehicleRoutPlannerCore-assembly VehicleRoutingConsole.cs
```

Comment: can you write the syntax?

Comment: i have posted picture of my path,so can you write the syntax according to that path

Comment: @rajeevpatidar You literally just add your path after `-pkg:`

Comment: I got solution   **mcs -r:YourDllName.dll VehicleRoutingConsome.cs**